# Bind IP to an Programm

Tags: windows-server-2008, debian

today i have experied some problems with few games called 7 days to die (Windows), Starbound (Win/Linux), Cubeworld (Win)!

Simply we provide gameservers on Windows and Linux host systems!

This works for Linux: http://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html The way we have done right now is the following,

Start Starbound, Cubeworld via WINE and use that ^ tool.

works fine.

7 Days to die doesnt work with wine (i think b/c of missing a Libary or somethink like that).

If you have a Solution for that it would be nice to see it in your comments.

We tried some stuff with Windows Virtual Loop back adater but seems not working.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Via a quick google search it appears that there is a tool called [forcebindip](http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) which may do what you want. There is even a [tutorial on how to use it](http://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/) on HowToGeek.

Comment: The problem is with forcebind is that it binds to an Interface (network Card) not to the IP it selfs. So like i have 10 ips on one Machine, with one Network Card.